# How can you view the Query Store settings for a database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-store

I see that you can use notion  like the following to set the query store configuration:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database name>   
SET QUERY_STORE (SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE = AUTO);
```

But how can I check to see what the current value for `SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE` is?

Comment: Have you looked at the DMV? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn818146.aspx

Comment: @SeanGallardy nice, that's exactly what I wanted (I saw that page but didn't notice the table name up top, doh!).  If you post your answer I'll mark it as the right one

Comment: https://github.com/Evdlaar/sp_WhatsupQueryStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be found (near the end) in the [sys.database_query_store_options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn818146.aspx) DMV.

```
SELECT size_based_cleanup_mode, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc
FROM sys.database_query_store_options
```

Comment: better to accept the answer 2.5 years late than never :P